# How to use Selenium Webdrive with C# to validate some errors messages from a Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium

I have a situation that all errors message will appear only in a excel file. I've never used selenium for validate a message error. I usually use selenium just for check information's error inside of a website. Please, help me to find a solution to resolve this challenge.

Thanks!

Comment: Selenium is a web driver, hence why you use it to check web sites.  Why do you think this would work with a windows application?

Comment: I don't know, I started to work with selenium recently. I ask for my collegues more seniors and they awnsered me that Selenium is just for check web sites. But, do you know if exist some tool that automated windows aplication? In this case would only work manual validation?

Comment: Did you google how to use C# and Excel? That sounds like what you are looking for. You can't use Selenium to interact with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Selenium WebDriver for desktop applications. It is for Web applications only.

There is tools available based on Selenium for automated testing of Windows Applications:
https://code.google.com/p/twin/

https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop

Comment: @rzdasil If this was helpful to you, please mark as answer.